# Is it safe to hook up a device with a higher voltage battery through a regulator like this?

Tags: batteries, voltage-regulator

So using a 6v 26 Ah battery and a 5v regulator, am I safe to hook it up to a 5v by 2.5 A max power draw device? I think so, I'm still get familiar with EE concepts though. What complications could arise? What is efficiency like on regulators, I know they heat up, so the must lose power.

[from the O.P.'s comment] The regulator in questions is [MC7805](http://datasheetz.com/data/Integrated%20Circuits%20(ICs)/Voltage%20Regulators%20-%20Linear/MC7805ABTOS-datasheetz.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditional LINEAR regulators indeed drop power by heating up. Newer-technology SWITCHING regulators only draw power for fractional amounts of time so that they produce very low heat compared to the old-fashioned ones.

Note, however that many (most?) regulators need some better margin to work with. You will need a rather good (better than average) regulator to produce a 5V output from a 6V input voltage.  Most 5V regulators you will find are not capable of operating on inputs as low as 6V. Now you MIGHT find a very "low-dropout voltage" regulator that can work with only 1 volt of differential.

There are also switch-mode regulators which can handle "drop-out" voltage down practically to zero (slightly more than 5V source for 5V output.

Comment: Yes, it's safe.  But no, a [venerable] 78XX linear regulator will not  work for 6V input and 5V output.  In the datasheet, notice "The input voltage must remain typically 2.0 V above the output voltage".  So, look for a low dropout linear regulator (LDO).